# C# error MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf

How does an Alert in c#?

I'm having too many problems,how can I fix it?

My C#:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string textbox1 = box1.Text;
        string textbox2 = box2.Text;

        string text1 = text.Text;


        if (textbox1 == "Jack")
        {
            MessageBox("Hello");
        } 
    }
}
```

The error is: "Error Context". Why?

Comment: call `Show` method. see this link: http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show to learn how to work with `MessageBox` in C#

Comment: Which method?,Can you write my code?,Because i don't understand,Sorry

Comment: You have wondefull answers here, so you not really need my code. but use my link to learn more. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

`MessageBox` is a class. You need to call the `Show` method:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

The [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.aspx) class contains many more overloads of the `Show` method that allow customization of the dialog.

Comment: You linked the wrong `MessageBox` class! He is using WPF

Comment: @Andy You are right. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Message Box is shown by calling `Show()` method like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Write Message here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `Show` method of `MessageBox` class:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessageBox.Show with the icon as well

Here:

```
MessageBox.Show("Error Message", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.Ok, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: Not function, "Error Context"!

Comment: @Loris812 , now check it, ' OK ' was wrong , it should be ' Ok ' , it will work now. If it works please select as correct answer. Thanks